# Order of Operations in Regular Expressions (solving a challenge)

Tags: javascript, regex

**I am working on a problem from FreeCodeCamp that involves me developing a Regular Expression that meets these four requirements:**

- Usernames can only use alpha-numeric characters.
- The only numbers in the username have to be at the end. There can be
  zero or more of them at the end. Username cannot start with the
  number.
- Username letters can be lowercase and uppercase.
- Usernames have to be at least two characters long. A two-character
  username can only use alphabet letters as characters.

**What I have decided on is `/[a-z]/ig`, which covers all of the test cases except for the following three:**

- Your regex should not match the string `BadUs3rnam3`
- Your regex should match the string `Z97`
- Your regex should not match the string `c57bT3`

What confuses me is that if I add numbers (`\d`) into my **Regex** then some of my simpler requirements ("Regex should match `JACK`") are now incorrect.

I was thinking that I could do something like:

```
/[a-b+?]*\d/
```

or this

```
/[a-b^0-9$]/
```

But that throws off things.

Can someone lend me a hand and explain how this might work?

Answer (score 2):

The patterns that you tried do not match because:

- The pattern `[a-b+?]*\d` matches optional chars `a` `b` `+` or `?` followed by a single digit, which makes the digit mandatory and matches not allowed chars
- The pattern `[a-b^0-9$]` only matches a single char `a` `b` `^` digit 0-9 or `$` and also matches not allowed chars

---

You could either match 2 or more chars a-z followed by optional digits, or match a single char a-z followed by 2 or more digits.

```
^[a-z](?:[a-z]+\d*|\d{2,})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Always start with a char a-z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-z]+\d*` Match 1 or more chars a-z and optional digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{2,}` Match 2 or more digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M9Saf7/1)

```js
const regex = /^[a-z](?:[a-z]+\d*|\d{2,})$/i;
[
  "aa",
  "JACK",
  "abc",
  "ab1",
  "Z97",
  "BadUs3rnam3",
  "c57bT3",
  "a",
  "0",
  "01",
  "a1",
  "a",
  "ab1a"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```